# Generate Spring Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, xml-configuration

I'm actually working in a huge project providing a server and client spring application. The client - for runtime concerns - is using a xml configuration of its beans **but** the server does **not**, leading to an immense start up time (at least 20 minutes) due to the classpath scanning. Which is ok for deployment in its production environment, but is a huge overhead for all the developers waiting for the server to start up may be several times per day.

My Question:

**Is there any *"easy"* way to switch from classpath scanning to a static configuration?**

I'm thinking of some kind of xml generation for instance. To me, it should be possible to generate a static configuration file the same way the configuration is done via classpath scanning at start up. Are there any concerns I don't know preventing something like that? Does there exist any kind of generator like that?

Comment: I highly doubt class path scanning is the issue here, using XML might shave off a bit of time (seconds) but the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Instead of using XML you can add the component-indexer which will store a snapshot of the context and reuse it for application start. That way you disable the component-scanning. However I highly doubt that it will improve your performance by much (which would be more or less the same gain when you would switch to XML). My guess is that your startup delay is due to some DB checks/syncs being done.